# Fetch specific data from json and store in table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to fetch specific data from external api and store it into my table in django. I am able to fetch all the data, but how do I send only specific data to the table.

My view.py file:

```
def post(self, request):

    api_key = "API-KEY"
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key={}'.format(api_key))
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    serializer = GetListSerializers(data = data)
    # serializer = GetListSerializers(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My Model.py file:

```
class GetList(models.Model):
    movieid = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My serializer.py file:

```
class GetListSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GetList
        fields = ('movieid', 'title')
```

Output of api is a dictionary i.e

```
{
"total_results": 10000,
"total_pages": 500,
"page": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "original_title": "Ad Astra",
        "vote_average": 6,
        "id": 419704,
        "poster_path": "/xBHvZcjRiWyobQ9kxBhO6B2dtRI.jpg",
        "backdrop_path": "/p3TCqUDoVsrIm8fHK9KOTfWnDjZ.jpg",
        "adult": false,
        "overview": "decades before boldly faced emptiness and silence in search of the unknown.",
        "original_language": "en",
        "genre_ids": [
            12,
            18,
            9648,
            878,
            53
        ],
        "video": false,
        "vote_count": 1749,
        "release_date": "2019-09-17"
    },....
```

I want to send id and title to table.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you receive in the `data` variable ? Maybe you only have to do a forloop on it and save the specific fields you need in your table.

Comment: Please be more specific. "how do I send only specific data to the table" isn't clear. Give an example of what you get and what you actually want. Or explain what your current code does that is unexpected behavior, like errors or wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you store data in DB using a Django model.

```
title = data['results']['original_title']
GetList.objects.create(title=title)
```

Additionally, you can skip the id field on the GetList model, because all Django models have a default auto-incrementing 'id' field. I'd also suggest renaming *GetList* to *Movie*, for readability.